# Handle AuthorizeAttribute answer

Tags: c#, owin, authorize-attribute

I did create custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that should handle Jwt Bearer token but the question is - now I'm receiving all answers, including 200 and 401 within Ok status, how I should change it in order to receive proper http status code? Here is how `AuthorizeAttribute` look like:

```
public class JwtAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string role;

        public JwtAuthorizeAttribute()
        {
        }

        public JwtAuthorizeAttribute(string role)
        {
            this.role = role;
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var jwtToken = new JwtToken();
        string json = String.Empty;
        var ctx = actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext();
        if (ctx.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return true;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
        {
            try
            {
                IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
                IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
                IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
                IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
                IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder);
                json = decoder.Decode(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter, SiteGlobal.Secret, verify: true);
                jwtToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtToken>(json);
                if (jwtToken.aud != SiteGlobal.Audience || jwtToken.iss != SiteGlobal.Issuer || role != jwtToken.role)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (TokenExpiredException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (SignatureVerificationException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, jwtToken.unique_name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, jwtToken.role));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", jwtToken.user_id.ToString()));
        actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

This is how controller look like:

```
[JwtAuthorize("Admin")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(CatalogueListDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
  {
    var result = await _catalogueService.GetCatalogues();
    if (result == null) return BadRequest(ActionAnswer.Failed.CatalogueNotFound);
     return Ok(result);
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "handle it in the controller"? The point is to not have to handle it in the controller at all.

Comment: @Crowcoder, the problem is that I'm receiving error message within Ok status, instead I'd like to receive proper server status.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to include the error, what is happening, and what is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a similar attribute by following some tutorials in the past. If authorized, i'm not returning true, but i return this:

```
return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
```

Maybe it's worth a check if this returns you the correct status code.